# Find kNN having reference in a table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn

I am working with PostgreSQL 12.2 and PostGIS 3.

I have been through a lot of posts talking about "Lateral joins" and other solutions but I am stuck with some incoherent results up to now.

I have two tables. One containing a list of airports.

```
CREATE TABLE app.apt_airports (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL
   , icao_code CHARACTER VARYING(16) NOT NULL
   , iata_code CHARACTER VARYING(4) DEFAULT NULL
   , name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NULL
   , refpoint geography(POINTZ,4326)
   , importance INTEGER NOT NULL
   , type INTEGER NOT NULL
   , status INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

The other table is a list of weather reports generated for some airports (not all).

```
CREATE TABLE metar_raw
(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sq$metar_raw_id'),
  icao_code CHARACTER(4) NOT NULL,
  time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  raw_metar text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT metar_raw_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id,icao_code,time)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (time)
```

For any given geographical coordinates I must be able to find the three closest airports having a weather report and find the latest one.

I am able to get the expected result if I query only for the closest airport with the following query:

```
SELECT apt.public_id
     , apt.name
     , mtr.time
     , apt.icao_code
     , mtr.raw_metar
     , st_y(apt.refpoint::geometry)::double precision as latitude
     , st_x(apt.refpoint::geometry)::double precision as longitude
     , ST_Distance(apt.refpoint, st_makepoint($2,$1)::geography)*0.000539957 as distance
     , degrees(ST_Azimuth(st_makepoint($2,$1)::geography, apt.refpoint::geography)) AS heading
FROM app.apt_airports apt
     INNER JOIN weather.metar_raw mtr ON (apt.icao_code=mtr.icao_code)
WHERE mtr.time > now() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
ORDER BY apt.refpoint <-> ST_Point( $2,$1) asc, mtr.time desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Please note that the table containting the weather reports grows quite fast and performance is kinda key here. The table contains several millions of records (reason why it is partitioned).

How to find the latest weather report for the three closest airport having one? (ignoring those not having weather reports)

Comment: What happens when you do `LIMIT 3`? How are the results incoherent? It's not clear from what your question where the issues lies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and question John.
When I put `LIMIT 3` the query returns the three latest weather reports for the nearest airport (three for the same airport) and not the latest report for the three nearest airports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are doing an inner join to `metar_raw`, this query will only return airports that do have a weather report.

You can try using [distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), which allows you to keep only one row per set, and a set is defined by the columns listed in your `distinct on ()` clause:

```
SELECT distinct on (apt.refpoint <-> ST_Point( $2,$1),apt.public_id)
       apt.public_id
     , apt.name
     , mtr.time
     , apt.icao_code
     , mtr.raw_metar
     , st_y(apt.refpoint::geometry)::double precision as latitude
     , st_x(apt.refpoint::geometry)::double precision as longitude
     , ST_Distance(apt.refpoint, st_makepoint($2,$1)::geography)*0.000539957 as distance
     , degrees(ST_Azimuth(st_makepoint($2,$1)::geography, apt.refpoint::geography)) AS heading
FROM app.apt_airports apt
     INNER JOIN weather.metar_raw mtr ON (apt.icao_code=mtr.icao_code)
WHERE mtr.time > now() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
ORDER BY apt.refpoint <-> ST_Point( $2,$1) asc, apt.public_id, mtr.time desc
LIMIT 3;
```

One quirk about distinct on: whatever columns or parameters are listed in your `distinct on()` clause, must be the first parameters listed in the `order by` clause. So in this case, even though you only care about having one record returned per airport (apt.public_id), we must include the distance comparison so that we don't just order on the apt.public_id in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Michael, your solution is spot on!
Thanks a million for your clear answer.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help